# styleStroke in Canvas not changing stroke color

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to change the color of the stroke(ie. line joining two points). Right now its coming in white color, while by default it should be of black.Also when i am trying to use styleStroke ="(any_color or RGB)", even then its not changing the line color. While the "lineWidth" property is working fine.

This is the java-script code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

var condition = 1;
var points = [];//holds the mousedown points
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

this.isOldIE = (window.G_vmlCanvasManager);
$(function() {
  /*   */

        if (this.isOldIE) {
            G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(myCanvas);
        }


        ctx.lineWidth = 2;


        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.src = "1.jpg";
        /* imageObj.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"; */



        function init() {
            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
        }

        /* // Draw  image onto the canvas */
        imageObj.onload = function() {

            ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
            var data1=ctx.getImageData(0,0,217,275)

        };




        /* // Switch the blending mode */
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';

        /* //mousemove event */
        $('#myCanvas').mousemove(function(e) {
            if (condition == 1) {


                ctx.lineJoin = "round";

                $('#posx').html(e.offsetX);
                $('#posy').html(e.offsetY);
            }
        });
        /* //mousedown event */
        $('#myCanvas').mousedown(function(e) {

            if (condition == 1) {

                if (e.which == 1) {
                    var pointer = $('<span class="spot">').css({
                        'position': 'absolute',
                        'background-color': '#000000',
                        'width': '5px',
                        'height': '5px',
                        'top': e.pageY,
                        'left': e.pageX


                    });
                    /* //store the points on mousedown */
                    points.push(e.pageX, e.pageY);

                    /* //console.log(points); */

                    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
                    var oldposx = $('#oldposx').html();
                    var oldposy = $('#oldposy').html();
                    var posx = $('#posx').html();
                    var posy = $('#posy').html();
                    ctx.beginPath();

                    ctx.moveTo(oldposx, oldposy);


                    if (oldposx != '') {
                        ctx.lineTo(posx, posy);
                        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
                        ctx.stroke();
                    }
                    $('#oldposx').html(e.offsetX);
                    $('#oldposy').html(e.offsetY);
                }
                $(document.body).append(pointer);
                $('#posx').html(e.offsetX);
                $('#posy').html(e.offsetY);

            }//condition
        });

        $('#crop').click(function() {
            condition = 0;

            /* //  var pattern = ctx.createPattern(imageObj, "repeat");
            //ctx.fillStyle = pattern; */
            $('.spot').each(function() {
                $(this).remove();

            })
            /* //clear canvas */

            /* //var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); */

            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 217, 275);

            ctx.width = 217;
            ctx.height = 275;
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
            /* //draw the polygon */
            setTimeout(function() {


                /* //console.log(points); */
                var offset = $('#myCanvas').offset();
                /* //console.log(offset.left,offset.top); */


                for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i += 2) {
                    var x = parseInt(jQuery.trim(points[i]));
                    var y = parseInt(jQuery.trim(points[i + 1]));


                    if (i == 0) {
                        ctx.moveTo(x - offset.left, y - offset.top);
                    } else {
                        ctx.lineTo(x - offset.left, y - offset.top);
                    }
                    /* console.log(points[i],points[i+1]) */
                }


                if (this.isOldIE) {

                    ctx.fillStyle = '';
                    ctx.fill();
                    var fill = $('fill', myCanvas).get(0);
                    fill.color = '';
                    fill.src = element.src;
                    fill.type = 'tile';
                    fill.alignShape = false;
                }
                else {
                    var pattern = ctx.createPattern(imageObj, "repeat");
                    ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
                    ctx.fill();
                    /* console.log(ctx) */

                    var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
                    /* console.log(dataurl) */




                    /* //upload to server (if needed) */
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php', false);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    var files = dataurl;
                    var data = new FormData();
                    var myprod = $("#pid").val();
                    data = 'image=' + files;
                    xhr.send(data);
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        console.log(xhr.responseText)
                        $("#myimg").html('<img src="Cropped_images/' + xhr.responseText + '.png"/>');


                    }

                    else
                    {console.log("Error")}



                }
            }, 20);

        });

   /* // } */
});

});




</script>
```

Comment: Please make a working example or fiddle.

Comment: You should draw on `mousemove`. Apparently you are drawing only on `mousedown`. Please move what you have on `mousedown` into `mousemove`

Comment: I came to know it was not changing color due to the "globalCompositeOperation" used. Since it was picking up the color from the background-color of the canvas, so i changed the bg-color to black. It worked for me.Thanks for the help though.